# How to inherit interceptor stack and override one of the intercetor in that?

Tags: struts2, interceptorstack

I need to inherit `paramsPrepareParamsStack` interceptor stack into `mystack` and need to override validation interceptor parameters. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the below code executes well..

```
<interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="ehspre2stack">
                <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack">
                    <param name="validation.excludeMethods">
                        list,loadedit,remove,execute,reset,loadAdd
                    </param>
                    <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
                    <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the entire stack into your struts.xml and override the parameters as needed:

```
       <interceptor-stack name="paramsPrepareParamsStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">your,methods,skip,validation</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">your,methods,skip,validation</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
```

Comment: What will happen if i specify as <interceptors>
   <interceptor-stack name="ehspre2stack">
    <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack">
     <param name="validation.excludeMethods">
      list,loadedit,remove,execute,reset
     </param>
    </interceptor-ref>
   </interceptor-stack>
  </interceptors>